# Mapping a query with different column names (sometimes in a different language) to a table in a different server

Tags: sql, sql-server, mapping, redgate

What is the best tool or method to map a SQL Server query to a SQL Server table with different column names?

Secondly and separately, is there a tool that considers objects and values in a different language. I attempted to use Redgate; however, the SQL Compare function does not allow for mapping with different column names.

Mapping is needed for different queries from different agencies who each use different table/column names. In some cases, the language for the columns and values are different (i.e., Italian, Spanish).

Comment: Are you looking to compare the schema definition (ie the type/size of the fields) or the actual data within the tables? If the latter, then SQL Data Compare is the tool you should be using, which does allow you to map columns with different names.

Comment: Thanks! I’m looking to do the latter; map the values in the table. I’ll try that tool.

Comment: Sounds like you want a view.

Comment: I want to map the values to an existing table.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Data Compare (not SQL Compare) lets you compare a table against a view. So If you create a view on the second table, giving it the column names used in the first table, then you can use the Tables and Views tab to map the table with the view.

Make sure you "include views" in the Options tab to see the views listed in the tables and views tab.